# Rails Switching from Webrick and LightSQL to MySQL and Apache

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apache

I'm currently using webrick and lightsql for my Rails 3 development app, but I've finished the app now and need to move it on to MySQL and Apache, because that's what DreamHost uses, and it's probably a more suitable production environment. The only problem is I've never done this in rails before, as this is my first rails app.

Can anyone please point me in the direction of some tutorials for both of these, or advise me how I'm supposed to do it? I'd be eternally grateful! I'll be doing this in development mode first, and testing everything, and if it all works in both of those then I'll begin deployment. I've never done a deployment before either, so that's another thing I have to figure out ><

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For change database to MySQL it´s easy.
You need add MySQL gem and remove SQLite gem:

```
gem mysql2
```

And change your database.yml (your_app/config/database.yml) to like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: yourdb_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123456
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: yourdb_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123456
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: yourdb_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123456
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

If you don´t have experiencie with apache, you can deploy easy in [webbynode.com](http://webbynode.com), this guys have a rapid deploy.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I've done deployments to Dreamhost using Apache/Passenger and there was just literally nothing to it; you specify the path to your project's root directory and then you are done.  I did not make any .htaccess files or otherwise try and configure Apache manually. I freeze all my gems and rails in vendor which simplifies it quite a bit.

petersonferreira probably has answered the database question adequately. I have not personally done that (I always develop in MySQL) so I do not know if you may find any platform differences that you need to manage in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of tutorials out there for deploying Rails apps on Dreamhost.

[Google is your friend.](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=dreamhost%20deploy%20rails%20tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Comment: Already found those. None of them are particularly helpful. I wouldn't have posted here if I didn't already search google.

Comment: Then I am afraid that we'll need some more information on what problems you are running into. It's been some time since I used Dreamhost but if I recall you simply make sure the app files are in the right path and you should be fine since they are using Passenger.